# Nodejs PDF to Image with pdf-image trouble

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

Im trying to convert a multi page pdf file to an image using the pdf-image https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-image i have no clue to set this up. Theres not enough documentation for complete noob.

Ive attached the code taken straight from the npm site.This code doesnt even throw an error. I know you need to install imagemagick but it doesn't say what to do with it. if anyone can help would be much appreciated

btw im using a windows machine

```
var PDFImage = require("pdf-image").PDFImage;
var pdfImage = new PDFImage("/tmp/slide.pdf", {
  combinedImage: true
});

pdfImage.convertFile().then(function (imagePaths) {
   // /tmp/slide.png 
});
```

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick and with Ghostscript. Both are needed. ImageMagick uses Ghostscript to convert PDF files. You could just use Ghostscript by itself if you want. Sorry, I know nothing about NodeJS

Comment: @fmw42 what do you mean by with ghostscript?? i did install imagemagick and ghostscript

Comment: You can use Ghostscript to rasterize a PDF all by itself. I do not know NodeJS, so cannot help on that issue. Your link above does not work for me.

Comment: @fmw42 sorry about that fixed the link, ill look into ghostscript

Comment: i ended up using imagemagic commands on nodejs got the same result in the end result but ive no clue if there is a performance difference

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import {default as pdfConverter} from 'pdf-poppler'
import path from 'path'

function convertImage(pdfPath) {

    let option = {
        format : 'jpeg',
        out_dir : 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\RootFolder\\pdfImageFolder',
        out_prefix : path.basename(pdfPath, path.extname(pdfPath)),
        page : 1
    }
// option.out_dir value is the path where the image will be saved

    pdfConverter.convert(pdfPath, option)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('file converted')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('an error has occurred in the pdf converter ' + err)
    })

}

export default convertImage
```

This is taken from [blog post](https://dev.to/gabriellaamah/how-to-convert-a-pdf-page-to-an-image-using-nodejs-4inm)